# An elliptic curve trivial over any extension unramified outside 7 and infinity?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-number-theory

Is there an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $E(K)$ is trivial for every finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ with discriminant a power of $7$ ?